# Can a player mark two different targets?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark

I have a player who plays a multi-class swordmage/warden. Each class gives him the capability to mark a target. Last encounter he used the marking ability of the swordmage as well as the marking ability of the warden to mark one enemy with each.

I understand that marking can't stack, but can a player mark two different targets? I always assumed if you mark a target, then you somewhat focus on it, right? So marking a second target should not be allowed, or should it?

Also to mention one marking ability is for close target, the other is for a rather distant target, like an archer.

Comment: The key here is the lack of ability to *enforce* multiple marks. Most classes only get to enforce their marks 1/round (via immediate actions).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no rule limiting the number of targets an individual can have marked at any given time.

A number of abilities, including the Warden's basic mark ability Nature's Wrath, explicitly state the possibility of marking multiple targets:

> a warden can mark each adjacent enemy until the end of the warden's next turn.

Marks from multiple sources are no exception to this.